# Printing the all the sorted field values in a mysql column ( in java)

Tags: java, mysql, database, resultset

I have a table like this

```
+-----------+-------------+
| attribute | score       |
+-----------+-------------+
| camera    |   0.0819958 |
| display   |    0.327983 |
| model     |     0.70521 |
| ram       | 0.000304832 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to sort the attributes according to the score and i want to print all of them. But when i execute the below code i get only one value. Please help.

```
String tb = "SELECT attribute from qvtemp order by score desc ";
statement = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(tb);
ResultSet rs5 = statement.executeQuery();
String g = null;
while (rs5.next()) {
    g = rs5.getString(1);
    } 
System.out.println(g);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the following from:

```
while (rs5.next()) {
g = rs5.getString(1);
} 
System.out.println(g);
```

To

```
while (rs5.next()) {
    g = rs5.getString(1);
    System.out.println(g);//bring it in loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you only see one value printed? That's because the print statement is outside of the loop body.